# Android Login with json

Tags: android, json, internal-server-error

I'm try to do the login on my company website using their API.
Basically when I run the Login I received response null, I don't know if is the server that doesn't receive my request or something else, because I tested my json object and is fine, I tested the POST request with username and password like parameters to my server and it works properly, so I don't know why my app doesn't comunicate with the server, it still come up Internal Server Error.

Here my code:

```
public void login(View button) {
    EditText userEmailField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userEmail);
    mUserEmail = userEmailField.getText().toString();
    EditText userPasswordField = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userPassword);
    mUserPassword = userPasswordField.getText().toString();

    if (mUserEmail.length() == 0 || mUserPassword.length() == 0) {
        // input fields are empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please complete all the fields",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return;
    } else {
        LoginTask loginTask = new LoginTask(LoginActivity.this);
        loginTask.setMessageLoading("Logging in...");
        loginTask.execute(LOGIN_API_ENDPOINT_URL);
    }
}
private class LoginTask extends UrlJsonAsyncTask {
    public LoginTask(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... urls) {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urls[0]);
        JSONObject holder = new JSONObject();
        JSONObject userObj = new JSONObject();
        String response = "";
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject();

        try {
            try {
                // setup the returned values in case
                // something goes wrong
                json.put("success", false);
                json.put("info", "Something went wrong. Retry!");
                // add the user email and password to
                // the params
                userObj.put("username", mUserEmail);
                userObj.put("password", mUserPassword);
                holder.put("user", userObj);
                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                StringEntity se = new StringEntity(holder.toString());
                post.setEntity(se);

                // setup the request headers
                post.setHeader("Accept", "*/*");
                post.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

                @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                response = client.execute(post, responseHandler);
                String code_response=response.getBytes().toString();
                json = new JSONObject(response);
                json.put(code_response, "");

            } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("ClientProtocol", "" + e);
                Log.e("Localize", e.getLocalizedMessage());
                Log.e("MESSAGE", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
                json.put("info", "Email and/or password are invalid. Retry!");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Log.e("IO", "" + e);
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.e("JSON", "" + e);
        }

        return json;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
        try {
            if (json.getBoolean("success")) {
                // everything is ok
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mPreferences.edit();
                // save the returned auth_token into
                // the SharedPreferences
                editor.putString("AuthToken", json.getJSONObject("data").getString("auth_token"));
                editor.commit();

                // launch the HomeActivity and close this one
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login_Page.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();
            }
            Toast.makeText(context, json.getString("info"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // something went wrong: show a Toast
            // with the exception message
            Toast.makeText(context, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } finally {
            super.onPostExecute(json);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the logCat:

```
09-14 13:05:47.385  13798-13798/com.example E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-14 13:05:47.385  13798-13798/com.example E/SpannableStringBuilder﹕ SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
09-14 13:06:05.044  13798-14159/com.example E/ClientProtocol﹕ org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException: Internal Server Error
09-14 13:06:05.044  13798-14159/com.example E/Localize﹕ Internal Server Error
09-14 13:06:05.044  13798-14159/com.example E/MESSAGE﹕ Internal Server Error
```

Thanks guys

Comment: You can use GSon library for request

Comment: Create a pojo and use GSon library to set pojo to string and use it inside stringentity

Comment: Internal server error means error on server side, so you should start looking from there. Check out, what does server get in request, so it would be easier to find out problem with client.

Comment: The server works fine because I tried to make an http request from the website https://www.hurl.it/ with username and password parameters and the server response is 200 Ok.. (ps I made the Registration process that is kind of the same and I receive the response with users registered, means that the code should be fine....

Answer (score 0):

Hi guys I wanted just say that I fixed the problem, just in case someone have the same issue, I fixed because the server wanted simple json instead of object.
After send the simple json I received 200 Ok.
Thanks guys